# Form Validation on Group of items

Tags: forms, validation

Here is the page: http://hawaiianoptics.com/visa

Customer can only select on product and then needs to select color of that product. Can only select one product and one color. What's the easiest way to do this?

Use a radio on all of the products then do separate validation on the dropdowns?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like the best way is to validate only the items that are going to be sent to the server. If you are going to send the data from the radio, validate that, if you are going to send data from the drop down, validate that as well

Comment: Hmm not sure what to do with that. I know how to validate a radio and send it and also a select list. Just want to make sure they cant select more than one product.

Comment: If you are looking for the best way to allow a user to select a single item, then yes, a radio button makes sense to allow only one selection. Then in your validation, you could just make sure that only one product is being sent to the server. Then at the server level you can validate that ensuring that only one product has been sent.